# how to pass an URL as parameter in a partial in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wish to add an export feature to the index views for several objects in my application. Index views all look the same, so they use partials.
Here is the index.html.erb for the Business Objects:

```
<% provide(:title, (t('ManagingBOs')))  %>
<%= will_paginate %>
<%= render partial: "shared/simple_export", locals: {this_path: business_objects_path} %>
<%= render partial: "shared/object_index", locals: {this_index: @business_objects} %>
<%= will_paginate %>
<br />
```

I would like the simple_export partial to define export links such as this, which works fine out of a partial:

```
Download:
  <%= link_to "CSV", business_objects_path(format: "csv") %> |
  <%= link_to "Excel", business_objects_path(format: "xls") %>
```

Unfortunately, the syntax `<%= link_to "CSV", this_path(format: "csv") %>` raises an **Undefined method** error.

How can I implement this partial ?

Comment: Please add the exact/full error message you're seeing.

Comment: Also, why do you want to pass `business_objects_path` via `this_path` to a partial, instead of just using `business_objects_path` in your partial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= link_to "CSV",   url_for(:format => 'csv') %> |
<%= link_to "Excel", url_for(:format => 'xls') %>
```

**WARNING** : This version would also work, but could be potentially dangerous

```
<%= link_to "CSV",   params.merge(:format => 'csv') %> |
<%= link_to "Excel", params.merge(:format => 'xls') %>
```

Should work fine, anywhere in your views, without having to use any extra variable.

Comment: Echoing back the params unfiltered can be used as a mechanism for clickjacking or other nefarious behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I suppose the first option is fine?

Comment: Yeah, usually its not a problem. Its just one thing to be aware of.

Answer (score 3):

When you do:

```
locals: {this_path: business_objects_path}
```

You are not passing the method `business_objects_path`. You're calling the method `business_objects_path` and passing the resulting string to the partial. Remember that parens are optional for method calls in Ruby.

If you want to pass a method in Ruby (a function reference) you use the `method` method:

```
locals: {this_path: self.method(:business_objects_path) }
```

However you can just use the polymorphic routes helpers to lookup the method instead.

```
<%= render partial: "shared/simple_export", resource_name: :business_objects %>
```

---

```
Download:
  <%= link_to "CSV", polymorphic_path(resource_name, format: "csv") %> |
  <%= link_to "Excel", polymorphic_path(resource_name, format: "xls") %>
```

Comment: You have a typo : polymorpic -> polymorphic.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks @EricDuminil

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very interesting and detailed explanation.